# How to create customized bins in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create bins for CUSTOMER_AGE in my data frame using the pandas cut function. I tried using the code below:

```
bins = [0,20,25, 30, 35, 40,45,50,55, 60,150]
labels = ['0-20yrs', '21-25 yrs', '26-30 yrs', '31-35 yrs','36-40 yrs', 
           '41-45 yrs', '46-50 yrs','51-55 yrs', '56-59 yrs', '> 60yrs']
df['BINS'] = pd.cut(df.CUSTOMER_AGE, bins, labels = labels,include_lowest = True)
```

This is the output i got:

```
CUSTOMER_AGE               BIN
 20                      0-20 yrs
 38                      36-40 yrs
 58                      56-59 yrs
 60                      56-59 yrs
 60                      56-59 yrs
 72                      > 60 yrs
 61                      > 60 yrs
 60                      56-59 yrs
 80                      > 60 yrs
```

I would like to know why only customers who are 60 years old fall under the '56-59 yrs' bin instead of '> 60yrs'.
But customers who are older than 60 years old fall in the correct bin which is '>60 yrs'

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `right=False` in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for change `closed='right'` to `closed='left'`:

> **right** : bool, default **True**
>
> Indicates whether bins includes the rightmost edge or not. If right == True (the default), then the bins [1, 2, 3, 4] indicate (1,2], (2,3], (3,4]. This argument is ignored when bins is an IntervalIndex.

```
df['BINS'] = pd.cut(df.CUSTOMER_AGE, bins, labels = labels,include_lowest = True, right=False)
print (df)
   CUSTOMER_AGE        BIN       BINS
0            20   0-20 yrs  21-25 yrs
1            38  36-40 yrs  36-40 yrs
2            58  56-59 yrs  56-59 yrs
3            60  56-59 yrs    > 60yrs
4            60  56-59 yrs    > 60yrs
5            72   > 60 yrs    > 60yrs
6            61   > 60 yrs    > 60yrs
7            60  56-59 yrs    > 60yrs
8            80   > 60 yrs    > 60yrs
```

For better understanding is possible check [Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html):

> A closed interval (in mathematics denoted by square brackets) contains its endpoints, i.e. the closed interval [0, 5] is characterized by the conditions 0 <= x <= 5. This is what closed='both' stands for. An open interval (in mathematics denoted by parentheses) does not contain its endpoints, i.e. the open interval (0, 5) is characterized by the conditions 0 < x < 5. This is what closed='neither' stands for. Intervals can also be **half-open** or **half-closed**, i.e. **[0, 5)** is described by **0 <= x < 5** (closed='left') and **(0, 5]** is described by **0 < x <= 5** (closed='right').

and also check it without `label` parameter:

```
df['BINS_l'] = pd.cut(df.CUSTOMER_AGE, bins, include_lowest = True, right=True)
df['BINS_r'] = pd.cut(df.CUSTOMER_AGE, bins, include_lowest = True, right=False)
print (df)
   CUSTOMER_AGE        BIN          BINS_l     BINS_r
0            20   0-20 yrs  (-0.001, 20.0]   [20, 25)
1            38  36-40 yrs    (35.0, 40.0]   [35, 40)
2            58  56-59 yrs    (55.0, 60.0]   [55, 60)
3            60  56-59 yrs    (55.0, 60.0]  [60, 150)
4            60  56-59 yrs    (55.0, 60.0]  [60, 150)
5            72   > 60 yrs   (60.0, 150.0]  [60, 150)
6            61   > 60 yrs   (60.0, 150.0]  [60, 150)
7            60  56-59 yrs    (55.0, 60.0]  [60, 150)
8            80   > 60 yrs   (60.0, 150.0]  [60, 150)
```

So if you can see `(60.0, 150.0]` it means `60.0 < x <= 150.0` (`60` values are excluded).

But in second column is `[60, 150)` it means `60 <= x < 150` (`60` values are included).