# use pandas cut to make two groups out of three

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with numbers range from 1 to 3

```
Pclass

3
2
2
1
1
2
```

I want to bin them into 2 groups:

second class = 3-2

first class = 1

with

```
cut_labels = [ "second class","first class"]

cut_points = [1,2,3]

df["Lux_normal"] = pd.cut(df["Pclass"], cut_points, labels=cut_labels
```

the bins are not correct, how can I bin them correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) should be used here, but a bit ovecomplicated and also replace all values under `1` and above `2` to misisng values, if only `1,2,3` possible values then `fillna` fix it.

First change order in `cut_labels` list and add `right=False` for left closed intervals and replace missing values by `second class`:

```
cut_labels = ["first class", "second class"]
cut_points = [1,2,3]

df["Lux_normal"] = pd.cut(df["Pclass"], 
                          cut_points, 
                          labels=cut_labels, 
                          right=False).fillna('second class')
```

But better here should be [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for replace by dictionary values, if no match get missing values, so is possible replace these values by `fillna` again:

```
d = {1: "first class", 2:'second class', 3:'second class'}
df["Lux_normal1"] = df["Pclass"].map(d).fillna('another class')
print (df)
   Pclass    Lux_normal   Lux_normal1
0       3  second class  second class
1       2  second class  second class
2       2  second class  second class
3       1   first class   first class
4       1   first class   first class
5       2  second class  second class
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted to learn to use pandas cut function, `right=False`does the reverse order right? , but why do I need to use `fillna('second class')` ?

Comment: @lordpotato - Because left closed values - it means `3` values not matching. So created NaNs and are replaced by `second class`

Comment: @lordpotato - I try to explain it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657178/how-to-create-customized-bins-in-python/58657220#58657220)